# why is Map and List instantiable and yet they are abstract classes in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
List list = List();
Map map = Map();
```

what is the reason behind instantiating List abstract class and Map abstract class and they are considered abstract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because they use factory constructors.

Using the `factory` keyword, it is possible to make a constructor redirect to another implementation of the interface.

As such we can write:

```dart
abstract class Something {
  factory Something() = _ConcreteSomething;

  void someMethod();
}

class _ConcreteSomething implements Something {
  @override
  void someMethod() { }
}
```

Comment: is there a 'default' concrete implementation of List abstract class that the factory constructor is linked to so that when List is instantiated the factory constructor returns a concrete implementation of the List abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looking at the list constructors in the dart SDK, we have this (and some others):

```
@Deprecated("Use a list literal, [], or the List.filled constructor instead")
external factory List([int? length]);  // List();

external factory List.filled(int length, E fill, {bool growable = false}); // List.filled();
```

Yes, they are *abstract* classes in dart, but their constructor implementations (just like the two constructors in the code above) are not written in dart code but somewhere else (in a native code, C++), hence the usage of the **external** keyword.

Without the **external** keyword, using only the **factory** keyword, one would have to return its existing instance or redirect to instance of a derived class in dart.