# Dart does not return expected runtimeType for a map object

Tags: dart

Trying to validate some data and I think I found a bug in Dart.  When attempting to get the `runtimeType` of a `Map`, Dart indicates that the map is not a map (see last line in example below).  The `runtimeType` of all maps return `_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>`.

How do I get around this?

```
'foo' is String; // true
0 is int; // true
[] is List; // true
{} is Map; // true
'foo'.runtimeType == String; // true
0.runtimeType == int; // true
[].runtimeType == List; // true
{}.runtimeType == Map; // false? WTF
```

Some more info.  I have a large schema to validate against and it would be very complex to do so without being able to store the various types I'm using (i.e. `String` is a `Type`, `int` is a `Type`, etc.) in variables.

```
// Valid
bool b = 'foo' is String; // true
  
// Invalid
Type t = String;
bool b = 'foo' is t; // The error message: The name ‘t’ isn’t a type and can’t be used in an ‘is’ expression.
```

Comment: [`Map` is an abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370049/).  It provides factory constructors that return an instance of a class that *implements* the `Map` abstract interface.  There are different types of `Map`s (e.g. `LinkedHashMap`, `HashMap`, `SplayTreeMap`) and there are different implementations when compiled natively and when transpiled to JavaScript.  This is why you should use `is` checks instead of performing equality checks against the `runtimeType`.

Comment: All the types I mentioned (`String`, `int`, `List`, and `Map`) are abstract classes with factory constructors.  `Map` is the only one that exhibits this problem. I can't use `is` because Dart will not allow it if the `Type` is stored in a variable, and I need to store the types in variables. See additional info added to question.

Comment: That `''.runtimeType` and `[].runtimeType` are `String` and `List` respectively is an implementation detail. `[].runtimeType` is *not* `List` for Dart for the web.  Furthermore, comparing `runtimeType` values will give you additional problems with generic types. `[].runtimeType == List` might be true (for the Dart VM), but that's really shorthand for `<dynamic>[].runtimeType == List<dynamic>`.  `[1].runtimeType == List` would be `false`.

Comment: Interesting that the web behavior is not the same as what I see on a PC.  Also I understand that `Map` has a factory constructor named `Map` and that is what you meant when you said it provides a factory constructor.  `String` and `int` also have factory constructors, just not named the same as the class itself like we see with `Map` and `List`.

Comment: You have not stated your original problem. Instead, your question seems to address problems with a specific solution you have in mind. Maybe there are other ways to represent your data in Dart, or Dart is not the right tool.

Comment: "Trying to validate some data",  is the first line of my post. That is the "original problem". My question goes on to bring up the subject of type validation, so I didn't think it was too much to assume that the reader would realize that the needed validation required type validation. The base data is JSON, so the ways to represent it are limited. The code is in a Flutter app, so Dart is the only option. I think it is clear from my post that what I'm concerned with is type validation. If there is something I can add to make that more clear, I'm all ears.