# How to make Dart recognize Type stored in variable for use in "is" statement?

Tags: dart

This question stems from another question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74384130/dart-does-not-return-expected-runtimetype-for-a-map-object).  The snippet below shows the problem.

```
// Valid
bool b = 'foo' is String; // true
  
// Invalid
Type t = String;
bool b = 'foo' is t; // The error message: The name ‘t’ isn’t a type and can’t be used in an ‘is’ expression.
```

Please let me know if there is some additional info I can provide if this question isn't clear for some reason.

Comment: You can't.  There currently isn't much useful that you can do with `Type` variables.  But also see https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/459 and https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2090.

Comment: (Neither of those issues addresses this specific question, but I think they'd help with your original goal.)